# How is the Ogre's greatclub damage constructed in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, damage

I'm currently working on a [roll20 script](https://github.com/mvgijssel/roll20_scripts/blob/master/animate.js) which will automatically convert a creature using the rules of [Animate Dead](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animate-dead/). Now I ran into an oddity while trying to recalculate the damage and attack for the **greatclub** attack of the [Ogre](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/giants/ogre/).

The attack is listed as follows

> Melee greatclub +7 (2d8+7)

The +7 attack is understandable (+3 bab, +5 strength modifier, -1 size modified = +7), but the +7 damage has me puzzled.

The [docs](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Damage) mention the following about how damage is calculated:

> When you hit with a melee or thrown weapon, including a sling, add your Strength modifier to the damage result.

But this would mean that the damage for the greatclub should be 2d8+5 and not 2d8+7. So where is the additional +2 coming from? The ogre also doesn't have any feats that would increase this number.

I've looked into the [Table: Weapon Damage Size Conversion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/#table-weapon-damage-size-conversion) as the Ogre is a large creature but this doesn't say anything about +2 bonus damage.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**The greatclub is a two-handed weapon**

As stated under the rules for two-handed weapons:

> Two hands are required to use a two-handed melee weapon effectively.
> Apply 1-1/2 times the character's strength bonus to damage rolls for
> melee attacks with such a weapon.

So, +5 * 1.5 = +7.5, dropping fractions gives +7.

Answer (score 14):

### The Ogre is wielding their greatclub *two-handed*

Immediately following the rule you've already found that states that a creature adds their strength modifier to damage with melee weapons, there is a corollary for [wielding a weapon two-handed](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Wielding-a-Weapon-Two-Handed):

> When you deal damage with a weapon that you are wielding two-handed, you add 1-1/2 times your Strength bonus (Strength penalties are not multiplied). You don’t get this higher Strength bonus, however, when using a light weapons with two hands.

A greatclub is a two-handed weapon (and not a *light* weapon), so the Ogre gets to add 1.5x their strength modifier to their damage. As is usually the case with fractional results, the resulting +7.5 is rounded down to +7.